# What am I doing wrong - grey squares on MapView

Tags: android, google-maps, android-manifest

I supplied the SH1 of my app to the: `https://code.google.com/apis/console`, then I entered the API I got to the map key of my app. and then exported as signed .apk.

All I can see is a grey squares instead of my map, although all features are working, I see no map view...

my Manifest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.adam.hems20"
    android:versionCode="20"
    android:versionName="3.0"
     >

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"
        />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="13"
        />

    <uses-permission android:name="in.adam.hems10.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"
        />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" 
        >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name="in.adam.hems10.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="in.adam.hems10.Settings"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_setting" 
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
    </application>



</manifest>
```

Am I missing something ?.... I'm really desperate with it.

thx :-(

Comment: You are attempting, somehow, to blend Maps V1 (`<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />`) with Maps V2 (`com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES`). This is unlikely to work well.

Comment: I would recommend deciding first what API you are going to use. Then, I would recommend that you work through a tutorial or other sample on that specific Maps API.

Comment: What do you mean by "what API you are going to use" ? I know there are 2 API types: 1.for debugging 2. for uploading your app. I copied to my app the correct API from the generated API I got from Google sys. but still I can't get map.. what line from Manifest should I delete to get the Map view ?

Comment: "What do you mean by "what API you are going to use" ?" -- there are two Android mapping APIs that use Google Maps: Maps V1 and Maps V2.

Comment: Right now I'm using the V1, but I think that I got an API from V2 website... am I right or that V1,V2 have the same API generator website area ? if the API is generated for the V1 same as V2, what should I fix in the Manifest for getting it to work ? (the SH1 is correct)

Comment: "am I right or that V1,V2 have the same API generator website area ?" -- I have no idea what a "generator website area" is. Maps V1 is https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/. Maps V2 is https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/.

Comment: I know that site and I have a debugging key already. But this is not what I needed... listen, I entered this site: https://code.google.com/apis/console this site is where I generated my  API key, is that was OK or I did wrong ?

Comment: That is for use with Maps V2. It is not for use with Maps V1.

Comment: OK, just now I saw that Google ain't support anymore with the V1 for deployment AIP key... so even if I wanted to, I can't deploy it anymore since March 18... What should I do in order to convert my MapView to be V2 ? thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CommonsWare already mentioned you are using both API and this is the reason you are getting gray squares instead of a map. Here is a blog post I wrote on how to implement Google Maps API V2:

[Google Map API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Comment: Guide looks very clear and cool, as far as I understand, the only thing to do in order to convert my app to be working as V2 is to make those changes you mentioned in your blog, so I don't need to change a thing in my Class that extends MapActivity, and leave it as 'extends MapActivity' ?

Comment: if you look carefully at the guide you will see: "8. Now create an Activity that extends from “FragmentActivity” , create an XML layout file for this activity and set it as the content View of this activity, in the layout write the following:"

Comment: 1. But I know that in V2 you can create a map using extends the Activity itself (not MapActivity or FragmentActivity)...
2. Can I still use the old methods I used with V1 ?

Comment: you can use an ordinary Activity and a MapFragment object for the map if you develop your app for API v11 and above. If you target lower API's then you have to use the FragmentActivity with SupportMapFragment object and of course to add the android-support-v4 library. You old mehtod from V1 can't be used as you are working with different objects.

Comment: okay I'll read the instructions on your site and Google's site.
thx.